# MIcrosoft Teams Custom App store accessToken

Tags: javascript, tabs, storage, microsoft-teams

I made a Microsoft Teams Custom App, I've already get the accessToken from my external api that athenticate the user.
My problem is: how I can I save the received accessToken into Teams context? If I can't do this, how can I pass it from my tab to my messageExtension?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please try storing the token in the in memory? try if that helps?

Comment: Hello, I've used localStorage as exmaple.

Answer (score 0):

finally I decided to use Table Storage for save and get the received accessToken.